# analyzing hacked website log : is there any link between ./etc and ./tmp when uploading files?

Tags: php, wordpress

One of my friends got hacked and asked me for help. This guy had a single shared host and uploaded like 20 websites on it and one of them got hacked and now all of them are full of shells.

I asked for a list of files that have been created or changed on the server and I got the list something like below.

The shell name is `accesson.php`  it first appears in

```
./etc/assets/images/accesson.php
```

and then in

```
./tmp/assets/images/accesson.php
```

log :

```
./etc
./etc/newsss.com
./etc/shsh.com
./etc/nck.com
./etc/pvf.com
./etc/pvf.com/@pwcache/info
./etc/lck.com
./etc/assets
./etc/assets/images
./etc/assets/images/accesson.php
./tmp
./tmp/assets
./tmp/assets/images
./tmp/assets/images/accesson.php
./mail
./mail/new
./mail/tmp
./mail/assets
./mail/assets/images
./mail/assets/images/accesson.php



./public_html
./public_html/images/2017/01/162210999.jpg.CROP_.cq5dam_web_1280_1280_jpeg-280x200.jpg
./public_html/wp-content/plugins
./public_html/.ftpquota
./public_html/backlinks/error_log
./public_html/app/images
./public_html/app/images/css_sprites.png
./public_html/app/index.php
./public_html/assets
./public_html/assets/images
./public_html/assets/images/accesson.php
./public_ftp
./public_ftp/assets
./public_ftp/assets/images
./public_ftp/assets/images/accesson.php

 ./irso.com
./irso.com/.ftpquota
./irso.com/wp-content/plugins
./irso.com/wp-content/themes
./irso.com/assets
./irso.com/assets/images
./irso.com/assets/images/accesson.php

./ncl2.com
./ncl2.com/assets
./ncl2.com/assets/images
./ncl2.com/assets/images/accesson.php
./cache
./cache/assets
./cache/assets/images
./cache/assets/images/accesson.php
./ssl
./ssl/assets
./ssl/assets/images
./ssl/assets/images/accesson.php


./efr.com
./efr.com/.ftpquota
./efr.com/assets
./efr.com/assets/images
./efr.com/assets/images/accesson.php
```

It seems `accesson.php` has been spread through all directories.  The interesting thing is it has been created with its directory  `/assets/images/`  even in the `/tmp`.

I thought since it first appeasers in `./tmp` it must be uploaded through some bug since all uploaded files first go to `./tmp`, but what about that `./etc`? It is even before `./tmp` Is there a link between the two?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I'm have trouble following and understanding your question. Could you please revise it and clearly state what you are asking

Comment: Are you asking if in Linux there is a symbolic link between /etc/ and /tmp? If this is your question, then this is a pure Linux question, not a security question. And this is something that you can check for yourself with `ls`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Deleted my answer on SO since that will likely be closed)

etc is a suggestive directory to attack because it should be owned by root and unwritable to anybody else.

```
$ ls -alZ / | grep tmp
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       etc
```

You know that, but I'm just saying that it is suggestive because I don't see any reason why it should be writable. It's probably that the script is just thrashing and trying to write everywhere on the filesystem, maybe the compromised program just happens to have write permissions at /etc/, probably so it can alter its own config file...or misconfiguration on /etc/.

My little script here is clumsy and only creates the directory but shows what I mean about thrashing:

```
find / -maxdepth 2 -type d -exec mkdir -p '{}'\/assets\/images \;
```

tmp is a good initial target for malware because everyone has write permission there and those files can be executed, albeit with limited permissions.

```
$ ls -alZ / | grep tmp
drwxrwxrwt. root root system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0       tmp
```

The breach looks like an attempt at escalation because if there was root access there would be no reason to write to tmp, or thrash, and the logs could be cleaned up. A good start is to enable selinux so that files that are not in specific locations for executables cannot be executed. Selinux would have prevented a lot of the thrashing too.

I don't know about efr, irso, nc12 but write permissions to ssl is definitely bad and do to misconfiguration. I'm guessing the entry happened through a clumsy php script based on the extra changes to public_html (index.php), that's just a guess.

Comment: thanx after all the whining i decided to post it here in case , makes sense i think accesson.php replicated by a script in all dirs